# One window per project

Tags: window, session

I am working on several projects right now. I want *a single* instance of Emacs to handle them all. What I want is a tmux-like behavior wherein every 'window' (in the Emacs sense) corresponds to a projects which contains buffers of the files related to that project. There are several windows, with each corresponding to a project and I should be able to switch between them (something similar to `C-b w`)

Is this functionality already present in some form? I guess it'll be cool to have as the other options are either:

- Have several instances of Emacs open.
- Have all files of all projects in a single instance which makes switching buffers a pain.

Comment: For project management, have you tried [perspective](https://github.com/nex3/perspective-el)?

Comment: Try this blog post on [Emacs as an advanced terminal multiplexer](https://iloveemacs.wordpress.com/2014/09/10/emacs-as-an-advanced-terminal-multiplexer/): you'll get Tmux-like behaviour. I just stumbled upon it, put it to work and it does what it advertises. On top you'll get `ace-jump-mode`, in itself a cool solution for quickly jumping around with your cursor in a buffer (if you don't already have it).

Comment: If you are willing to invest some initial setup time to define conditions for projects, you can allocate them to one frame each and use `frame-bufs`.  See also **How to intercept a file before it opens and decide which frame** -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame -- to display a buffer in a target frame, and you can use `frame-buffs--add-buffer` in conjunction to get the frame associated.   You can marry `frame-bufs` with `tabbar` and associate/remove buffers dynamically:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10112/2287

Comment: Here is the link to `frame-bufs` to associate buffers with a particular frame:  https://github.com/alpaker/Frame-Bufs/blob/master/frame-bufs.el

Comment: @cutejumper Perspective is perfect. You could write it as an answer so that I could tick it correct.

Comment: @sudeepdino008 Sure. See http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20709/5482.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [perspective](https://github.com/nex3/perspective-el) to manage projects. From its README:

> perspective.el provides multiple workspaces (or "perspectives") for each Emacs frame. This makes it easy to work on many separate projects without getting lost in all the buffers.
>
> Each perspective is composed of a window configuration and a set of buffers. Switching to a perspective activates its window configuration, and when in a perspective only its buffers are available by default.

There is also another version [persp-mode](https://github.com/Bad-ptr/persp-mode.el), which is a little different from the original one. The perspectives are shared among frames and the states can be saved to the disk.

If you're using [projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile), there is also a perspective [integration](https://github.com/bbatsov/persp-projectile).

Answer (score 5):

You can try [eyebrowse](https://github.com/wasamasa/eyebrowse) mode, which manages multiple (perhaps complicated) window layouts. You can switch between window configurations with keystrokes such as `C-c C-w 1` and `C-c C-w 2`.

Comment: Eyebrowse shares buffer between workspaces. That might be undesirable

Answer (score 2):

A "barebones" solution might to use `C-x r w` to record the current window state and `C-x r j` to get back to an earlier one.

Answer (score 2):

I use a combination of a couple different packages.

Most importantly, I use [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) for working on a "project" and fuzzy-finding files. I use multiple frames, one for each project I'm currently working on. You really only need to know `C-x 5 2` and `C-x 5 0` to create/kill a frame. To manage switching between projects and for storing the state of window configuration/splits, I use [Workgroups for windows (for emacs)](https://github.com/tlh/workgroups.el).

I like this setup because I can potentially swap out one package for another.