# Can Emacs 25 use the new macOS Sierra tab features?

Tags: osx, frames, gui

Can Emacs 25 on macOS leverage the [new tab features](http://www.howtogeek.com/275155/how-to-add-tabs-to-almost-any-app-in-macos-sierra/) introduced in [macOS Sierra](http://www.apple.com/macos/sierra/) (10.12)?

If not, what is required for it to start supporting tabs?

Comment: I haven't updated to macOS Sierra, but there is [tabbar-mode](https://github.com/dholm/tabbar)  which adds tabs to emacs. You might want to check that out

Comment: Emacs 25 was not developed to be compatible with all the new features of MacOS Sierra, as both are recent releases.  See this related thread that provides various `tabbar` configurations, including, dynamic adding/removing tabs that are frame-local -- **Browser-style 'tabs' for emacs?**:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10081/browser-style-tabs-for-emacs

Comment: @lawlist do you think it's wise to update to macOS Sierra right now? Or should I wait for a new major release of  `emacs` before jumping the gun? Sorry for going off topic.

Comment: @Chakravarthy Raghunandan -- I generally estimate 1 to 2 days to work out problems with a new version of OSX, a lot of cursing, a lot of Googling, paying for new versions of certain programs that used to work (such as Parallels) but no longer work correctly, and in some cases still do not work correctly and then wait/see if bug fixes ever come.  I generally only only use a new version of OSX when I buy a new computer, or when I need it for something special -- e.g., to recognize a new video card for modern day video games on an older Mac Pro tower.  If you have free time, then . . . :)

Comment: @lawlist this is the first time I'd be updating my 13 RMBP. So, was just being cautious. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: It looks like these tabs are purely created by the window manager. I'm not a mac user, but kde-plasma has (had?) a similar feature which was working fine with all versions of emacs I tested it on.

Comment: To support my guess, from your link: "But developers don’t have to do anything in order for this functionality to work. This means that even applications that haven’t been updated in years can, in theory, work well."

Answer (score 1):

I use [elscreen](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsLispScreen) for tabs.  I don't think you have to rely on the OS to get tabs.

[image]

Comment: I want to use standard macOS widgets and keybindings for navigating tabs (Cmd-[ and Cmd-]), so this is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: with elscreen the commands will be `C-z n` & `C-z p`, I pretty sure you can rewire  these keybindings to `Cmd-]` & `Cmd-[`. 
But I am guessing you want native osx tab support, which I dont think is present in emacs as of now. Atleast not in the cocoa build that I use.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, this is now available in [railwaycat's Mac port](https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport) with `mac-toggle-tab-bar` which seems to have a default binding of `C-S-tab`.