# Emacs Dired `C-x C-j` opens a new frame instead of a new window

Tags: dired, window, frames, aquamacs

I am using Aquamacs 3.3  GNU Emacs 25.1.1 and Dired+. Sometimes the key sequence `C-x C-j` opens the Dired buffer in a new frame instead of a new tab in the running frame.

I want the behaviour that the the Dired buffer is opened in a new tab always.
What can I do?

Comment: Did you really mean **tab**, or did you mean Emacs *window*? I edited it to say the latter, but please change it back if I was wrong. (You wrote "window" where you apparently meant "frame" - I changed that too.)

Comment: Perhaps what you see comes from Aquamacs. Dired+ just leaves `C-x C-j` bound to `dired-jump`, which does not open either a new frame or a new window.

Comment: FYI -- for anyone who is curious about Aquamacs v. Emacs as to the tabbar library:  Aquamacs is distributed with a built-in version of tabbar with some modifications to said library.  The generic/vanilla version of Emacs does not ship with Emacs.  Here is a link to various tabbar configurations for the generic/vanilla version of Emacs:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10081/browser-style-tabs-for-emacs  The following link to marmalade contains installation instructions:  https://marmalade-repo.org/

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason for the behaviour myself. It is not a dired problem. Aquamacs has the Options menu where you can select "Show buffers in new frames" what was set accidentally.