# Open new frame when switching between projects in projectile

Tags: init-file, projectile

Regularly I am working in several projects at the same time, `projectile` has been great for helping me with all the mess, but now,  I would like to open a different frame per project, i.e., If I switch to the project `one` I want that in a new frame.

Is that possible? Could you provide with an example snippet for my `init.el`?

Comment: A quick Google came up with `C-c p 5 d`:  "Switch to a project directory and show it in another frame."  I don't use projectile, but I do organize by frames using this custom function contained in the answer of the linked thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame  Buffers can be associated with a particular frame using Frame-Bufs by Alp Aker:  https://github.com/alpaker/Frame-Bufs   And, here is an example of how to marry tabbar with frame-bufs:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10112/2287

Comment: You are right regarding that command, but the thing that I want (I maybe I din't explain my self) is, not open a new frame inside the project (that is the thing that `C-c p 5 d` does) but *switch* to a new project and open it in a new frame, so all the buffers related to that project will be open in the new frame.