# emacs tabbar -- how to get tabs for all buffers displayed in one go, regardless of extension?

Tags: tabbar

I use, and love, tabs, using the following in my .emacs:

`(require 'tabbar)
(tabbar-mode 1)
(global-set-key [(control shift iso-lefttab)] 'tabbar-backward-tab)
(global-set-key [(control tab)]       'tabbar-forward-tab)`

Since upgrading my distro a few months back (i'm sure it wasn't true before that), i've found that if i load several files with different extensions, then the tabs appear in different groups;  e.g.,

`emacs junk1.txt junk4.txx junk2.txt junk3.ttx junk9.txt`

gives me one "screen" (if you see what i mean) that has tabs for junk1.txt, junk2.txt, and junk9.txt;  and another with tabs for both junk4.txx and junk3.ttx (and yes, those two do have different extensions).

I can, of course, switch buffers to move between "screens" (and, err, between buffers);  but what i want is to have tabs for ALL my files  visible in a single "screen", so i can tab through all of them.   Any ideas how to achieve that (or for that matter, why i don't currently get that behaviour)?

Fwiw:
GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-mageia-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.7) of 2019-04-12

Thanks,
ian

Comment: How about trying out `(setq tabbar-buffer-groups-function (lambda () (list "All")))` from the Emacs tabbar wiki page?  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabBarMode  To try it out, just type:  `M-x eval-expression RET` ... copy and then paste the code into the minibuffer and then press the `RET` key.  If it works for you, then you can add that to your `.emacs` file underneath the `(require 'tabbar)` statement.  The following link contains some additional tabbar configuration ideas you may want to check out:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10081/browser-style-tabs-for-emacs

Comment: Oo, yes, that's pointed me in the right direction -- in  my ignorance, i hadn't known of the "groups" function, which is clearly at the root of this issue.   Thanks!

Comment: Umm, so how do i mark this is "solved"?

Comment: Inasmuch as my comment "pointed [you] in the right direction ...", it would appear that you had something slightly different in mind as the ultimate solution to your issue.  Therefore, it may behoove you to write-up your own answer; and, if needed, revise the question to make your issue more clear for future people who visit this thread.  I believe there is a 24 or 36 hour waiting period (or something like that) to accept your own answer, so check back when the waiting period has lapsed and then you can place a checkmark next to your answer to mark the issue as being solved.

Comment: It was a pretty strong pointer!  And thanks for the additional suggestions....

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to lawlist's enlightening suggestions, and a bit of subsequent googling, i was able to figure out the fix, defining my tabbing groups as needed by adding this into my .emacs:

```el
(defun my-tabbar-buffer-groups ()
  (list (cond ((string-equal "*" (substring (buffer-name) 0 1)) "emacs")
              ((eq major-mode 'dired-mode) "emacs")
              (t "user"))))
(setq tabbar-buffer-groups-function 'my-tabbar-buffer-groups)
```